# Sublime Text - international keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

I've an Italian keyboard and I'm using Sublime Text 3.
A lot of keyboard shortcuts are wrong and it's not possible to use them. Is there a way to import ALL the shortcuts for a different layout?